# Add n number of fields in django model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I want to add unlimited fields in the Django model.
[Actually, I want my model to look like this, Is it Possible ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeE9F.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but in a somewhat different way: Namely, by creating another model (called `Choice`, for instance) and letting several `Choice` objects point to the same `Question` by using a `ForeignKey` relationship. This way there can then be arbitrarily many `Choices`. Django's seven-part tutorial explains precisely how to create such an app. I highly recommend to work through it start to finish: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

It will exactly as picture

in admin panel

`admin.py`

```
class AnswersInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answers

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AnswersInline
    ]

admin.site.register(Question,QuestionAdmin)
```

`modelpy`

```
class Question(models.Model):
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='User Name')
    Question = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Question')
    CorrectAnswer = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Hidden Answer')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Question}" 

class Answers(models.Model):
    QuestionId = models.ForeignKey('Question', models.DO_NOTHING)
    Answer = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='User Name')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Answer}"
```